# Inner join - count and sum of field

Tags: sql

I have two tables `editors` and `title_editors` that I am trying to run an inner join query to show all editors and how many books they edit. I am not getting the desired result but a total sum of all books edited. How can list the name of all editors and how many books they edit and  arrange the report so the editor editing the most books is listed first? [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47bd4/1)

Query

```
SELECT (e.first_name || ' ' || e.last_name) as Editor_Name, SUM(te.editor_order) as Books_Edited FROM editors e
INNER JOIN title_editors te ON te.editor_id = e.editor_id ORDER BY SUM(te.editor_order);
```

Table Schema

```
create table editors    (editor_id char(11) not null,   editor_lname varchar(40) not null,  editor_fname varchar(20) not null,  editor_positon varchar(12) null,    phone char(12) null,    address varchar(40) null,   city varchar(20) null,  state char(2) null, zip char(5) null,   ed_boss char(11) null );
create table title_editors  (editor_id char(11) not null,   title_id char(6) not null,  editor_order tinyint null);
```

Comment: In your SQLfiddle example, you have it setup with MySQL, but are using the `||` operator for concatenation. That isn't normally supported in MySQL - instead concatenation is done like `CONCAT(e.first_name, ' ', e.last_name)`  Are you actually using Oracle or a different database?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, its sql. Sorry, it wasnt letting me do `oracle`.

Comment: The Schema isn't Oracle datatypes. Still, adding the GROUP BY to your query should fix the SUM().

Comment: @Shawn, sorry just realized this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the comment about CONCAT, you are missing your GROUP BY, and a DESC at the end of your ORDER BY to get them sorted the way you want.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(e.editor_fname,' ',e.editor_lname),
  SUM(te.editor_order)
FROM
  editors e
INNER JOIN
  title_editors te
  ON te.editor_id = e.editor_id
GROUP BY
  e.editor_fname,
  e.editor_lname
ORDER BY
  SUM(te.editor_order) DESC;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47bd4/28

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47bd4/22

Just GROUP your results.

```
SELECT (CONCAT(e.editor_fname,' ',e.editor_lname)) as Editor_Name
  , SUM(te.editor_order) as Books_Edited 
FROM editors e
INNER JOIN title_editors te 
  ON te.editor_id = e.editor_id 
GROUP BY e.editor_fname,e.editor_lname
ORDER BY Books_Edited;
```